# Jquery phone mask not working in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I had a webform page call newcall.aspx with one textbox phone number. The phone number is masked (999)999-9999 It worked perfectly in a regular webform.

However we changed it to MVC. We have a Sitemaster and we place  into newcall.aspx. My script was working perfectly, but it is not working in MVC can anyone tell me what I am missing.

MVC code (newcall.aspx)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NewCall.aspx.cs" Inherits="HITAssist.NewCall" ValidateRequest="false" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="FTB" Namespace="FreeTextBoxControls" Assembly="FreeTextBox" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

        <span class="Label">Phone Number Main:</span>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Tb_Main_Phone" runat="server" Width="250"></asp:TextBox>

        <span class="Label">Phone Number Secondary:</span>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Tb_Second_Phone" runat="server" Width="250"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Js/jquery.maskedinput-1.4.1.min.js">   </script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$('#Tb_Main_Phone').mask('(999) 999-9999');

$('#Tb_Second_Phone').mask('(999) 999-9999');

</script>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What is the HTML that renders the inputs?  Please add this to your question.

Comment: Without seeing more markup, I'm simply guessing, but most likely you have this at the top of the page, so when the script attempts to apply the mask, the input hasn't been rendered yet. An alternative problem could be that, depending on the "render mode" you're using, the ID of the input doesn't match (using master pages changes the generated names and IDs of the server controls).

Comment: Use your browser's developer console (normally activated by hitting the F12 key) and inspect the generated markup. I assume you'll see something other than `Tb_Main_Phone`, etc., as the ID of your inputs.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks to Tieson T. You are right Tb_Main_Phone is auto reassigned to MainContent_Tb_Main_Phone because of <asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"> . So changing '#Tb_Main_Phone' to '#MainContent_Tb_Main_Phone' solved the problem. Thank you